# G1: What are the differences between mixed gc and full gc?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, g1gc

For garbage first collector, **young gc** means performing gc in young generation only and  **mixed gc**  would clean both young and old generation.

So what is **full gc**? Why it lasts longer than **mixed gc**?

I've done some searching but I didn't find any post that explains **full gc**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Oracle [G1 GC blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/g1gc/entry/g1_gc_glossary_of_terms) and [technetwork article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/g1gc-1984535.html)

***Young GC:***

The collection set of the *Young GC* includes only young/survivor regions.

***Mixed GC:***

The collection set of the *Mixed GC* includes both young/survivor regions, but also old regions.

*Humongous Objects and Humongous Allocations*

**For G1 GC**, any object that is more than half a region size is considered a "**Humongous object**". Such an object is allocated directly in the old generation into "**Humongous region**s". *These Humongous regions are a contiguous set of regions.*

***Dead Humongous objects are freed*** at the end of the marking cycle during the cleanup phase also during a full garbage collection cycle.

In-order to reduce copying overhead, the Humongous objects are not included in any evacuation pause. *A full garbage collection cycle compacts Humongous objects in place.*

Generally a **Full GC** cleans the entire Heap – ***both Young and Tenured spaces (old gen)***

On a different note, you have to worry about how much time "application threads were stopped" irrespective of GC type :  Young GC or Full GC etc.

Comment: In fact I've read this post.  `Generally Full GC cleans entire Heap` answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: One more question: what algorithm will G1 use when performing full gc? Full GC is much slower just because it cleans all regions?

Comment: Full GCs: Currently G1 full gc is single threaded and very slow, we should try to avoid full gcs as much as possible.

Comment: does jvm print a log every time Humongous Allocation happens?

Answer (score 4):

The g1 divides the heap into regions, where the young generation and the old generation consists of several regions each.
A young GC collects some regions (not all), however, all of them are assigned to the young generation. A mixed GC collects some regions (not all), some belong the young generation, at least one to the old generation. A full GC collects all regions, and, in consequence, the young and the old generation.

Answer (score 2):

Under normal conditions G1 should only run young and mixed collections to meet its pause time goals.

Full GCs are a fallback mechanism and likely to violate those goals. They occur when mixed GCs aren't able to keep up with allocations, when a humongous allocation could not be satisifed or when a GC is requested with `System.gc()` and some other conditions.

Logging with `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` should include a cause for full collections.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between young and mixed GC is:

- Mixed GC contains the old regions reclamation (1/8 of old regions by default.)
- Mixed GC will be triggered when IHOP is reached. (By default when the old gen > 45%.)

From Oracle documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/gctuning/garbage-first-g1-garbage-collector1.html

> Adaptive IHOP tries to set the Initiating Heap Occupancy so that the first mixed garbage collection of the space-reclamation phase starts when the old generation occupancy is at a current maximum old generation size minus the value of -XX:G1HeapReservePercent as the extra buffer.

For full GC,

> After space-reclamation, the collection cycle restarts with another young-only phase. As backup, if the application runs out of memory while gathering liveness information, G1 performs an in-place stop-the-world full heap compaction (Full GC) like other collectors.

> The reason that a Full GC occurs is because the application allocates too many objects that can't be reclaimed quickly enough. Often concurrent marking has not been able to complete in time to start a space-reclamation phase.